# How can I use a single-dimensional array for Roman Numerals?

Tags: java, arrays

New programming student over here and I'm creating a program that converts a roman numeral input to it's decimal number. I'm working on a conversion method right now and I have to use a single dimensional array so here is what I did:

```
public static int numberConversion(int number) {

    char[] romanChar = new char[8];
    romanChar[I] = 1;
    romanChar[V] = 5;
    romanChar[X] = 10;
    romanChar[L] = 50;
    romanChar[C] = 100;
    romanChar[D] = 500;
    romanChar[M] = 1000;
```

But obviously something isn't right because I get an error from Netbeans in each of those 7 lines that say

> cannot find symbol. symbol: variable I

I know it's wrong, but how can I go about putting the values in for these roman numeral characters the right way using a single dimensional array?

Comment: use a `java.util.Map`? There's no "char" index. If you really want a map you could use the ascii index (ie. letter - 'A') but that's bad design IMHO

Comment: I'd suggest you post the assignment verbatim. We have no idea what you're trying to do, and how the array is supposed to be used for the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public enum RomanNumerals
{
    I (1),
    V (5),
    X (10),
    L (50),
    C (100),
    D (500),
    M (1000);

    private final Integer value;

    RomanNumerals(Integer value) 
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        System.out.println("The roman numeral 'V' value is: " + V.value);
    }
}
```

I think using an enum is the best solution.  It provides immutable (constants) values; which is really what needed for this implementation.  The value and characters of the Roman Numerals cannot change at all.  Of course, the output is:

```
The roman numeral 'V' value is: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that is make java an important language is that Java is a Object Oriented language so use it.

For your example create a class say RomanChar with symbols as char and values as integers like this :

```
Public class RomanChar{
    public int value;
    public char romanCharamcter;
}
```

Comment: This is not really a good solution because the values could be changed. An optimal solution should provide the roman numerals as constants.

Comment: @hfontanez I could recommend Map for that reason but since OP have no experience with array, I though map would be very hard for him.

Comment: but the problem with a Map is that it is not immutable. Roman Numerals in real life are constants. The software object to represent it should also be constant. If you use a class, the best thing to do is to add these values as such. However, an enum is a better alternative to class constants.

Comment: @hfontanez I like the idea of your answer that enum are immutable and for that I vote you up. But you must understand there is not always one solution to a question in programming as long as I see you are just a learner in programming, try to learn new Idea from others instead of resisting against other opinion(like mine and another answer that is deleted from here)

Comment: I never said that my solution is the only solution. I did say, however, that whatever solution is implemented for this case must provide two things: 1) immutability, and 2) accept no duplicates. That is an implicit requirement due to the nature of Roman Numerals. Any solution short of that, is not a good solution.

Comment: @hfontanez in fact you said that, with commenting on every other answer and voting them down. Also my answer is not a complete answer (usually I dont post complete answer for newbies so that they do some research and learn more) I just want OP to learn about the very basic concepts of OOD and I suggest you read about OO programming too. But I'm not like you to chat about 2 reps, so I'm sorry if OP and nobody else than me, likes your solution. Try to learn programming here, not begging for reps. Have a good day sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64572/discussion-between-ali-amiri-and-hfontanez).